# SVN Noob: quick summary of how to use it?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

[for those not following along at home, this is the sequel to [Rolling My Own Version Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811562/rolling-my-own-version-control) ;)]

So i gave in and installed TortoiseSVN (to work with a friend on a project, my personal version control is alive, well, and working as i want it). Having never seriously used one of these before, can someone give me (a link to a) concise explanation of such things as tags and how to use them, and anything else i should know before using it to work on a project with one other user?

I've seen [this eBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) and i'll certainly read it, however i'm looking for something to the effect of a "cheat sheet" or maybe something a little larger.

Forgot to mention, i'm on windows.

Comment: Have you looked for documentation at the homepage?

Comment: That, apparently, would be the book Mitch posted :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setup your repository with something like:

> /tags
>
> /trunk
>
> /branch

- Put the latest version of your code in **trunk**
- Tag releases or builds into a version-named folder in **tags** (consider these readonly)
- Branch releases into a version-named folder in **branch** (these are readwrite bugfix branches)

*Tags/branches do not use up extra space until new revisions are committed into them. To that end, our build process automatically creates a tag for each build (not necessary, but simply an example of their usage)*

The general flow is:

1. `Checkout` a repository (usually a specific branch or trunk) locally
2. Make changes
3. `Update` to merge changes (and resolve conflicts)
4. `Commit` the changes back into the repository

Other things to consider:

- Renaming files/folders. Use SVN -> Rename whenever possible to ensure you keep your history.
- Complex changes. If you are going to rename a folder *and* move files within it, try to commit one change at a time. Multiple deletes/moves/renames/adds within the same tree can sometimes cause SVN to get confused. You'll learn which specific scenarios to be careful of yourself over time.

The only other feature of note is adding a property (files `Properties -> Subversion -> Properties`) "needs-lock" with the value of "*". This will restrict the file to be modified by one user at a time (until they release the lock). Useful for file databases like SQLite, since they are binary and cannot be merged.

You can learn the rest yourself by simply playing around with it.

Answer (score 5):

Check out the [RedBean SVN free ebook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/). It's an excellent reference, containing info on branching, Tags etc

Also: Phil Haack's article [Quickstart Guide to Subversion on SourceForge](http://haacked.com/archive/2006/02/22/QuickstartGuidetoSubversiononSourceForge.aspx)

Comment: Saw that, but not sure it falls under the banner of "concise"... I'll look at it again though, see if it has a quick intro suitable for me.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of free resources on that topic on the internet. Like:

- [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/)
- [Short Tutorial](http://artis.imag.fr/~Xavier.Decoret/resources/svn/index.html)

Best wishes,
Fabian

Comment: Forgot to mention, i'm on windows